# Reversing permutation of an array in Java efficiently

Tags: java, algorithm, arrays, dictionary

Okay, here is my problem:

Im implementing an algorithm in Java and part of it will be following:
The Question is to how to do what I will explain now in an efficient way.

given:
array a of length n
integer array perm, which is a permutation of [1..n]

now I want to permute the array a, using the order determined by array perm,

i.e.
a=[a,b,c,d], perm=[2,3,4,1] ------> permutedA[b,c,d,a],

I figured out I can do that by iterating over the array with: permutedA[i]=a[perm[i]-1], (-1 because the permutation indexes in perm start with 1 not 0)

Now I want to do some operations on permutedA...

And now I want to do the reverse the permute operation.
This is where I am not sure how to do it. 
Note that a can hold an item more than once, i.e. a=[a,a,a,a]

Now I thought that using a Hashmap instead of the the perm array will help. But I am not sure if this is the best way to do.

Comment: What do you mean by reversing the permute operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty example in Python:

```
def permute(a, perm):
    result = []
    for x in perm:
        result.append(a[x - 1])
    return result

def invPermute(a, perm):
    result = [None] * len(perm) # Build a result list of correct length
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        result[perm[i] - 1] = x
    return result
```

Tested with:

```
>>> perm = [2,3,4,1]
>>> invPermute(permute("ABCD", perm), perm)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Answer (score 5):

Think you mean

```
ShuffledA[i] = a[perm[i]-1]
```

At the time you shuffle you can build the inverse shuffle:

```
 inverseperm[perm[i]-1] = i + 1
```

Which builds

```
 inversePerm[4 1 2 3]
```

And you then apply your existing algorithm to [b c d a] yielding your original [a b c d]

Answer (score 2):

Why permute it?  Why not just access the items using the perm value.

```
for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
  String val = a[perm[i]-1];
}
```

Comment: It may not work for the OP's needs, depending on why he wants to permute, operate, and then de-permute, but it sure sounds tidy to me.

Answer (score -1):

what's wrong with:

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(theArray));
```

Comment: its a random shuffle i want a specific permutation determined by perm array, maybe I named the method irritating, it should be more permute() instead of shuffle()